# Midnight Commander Options/Appearance menu is missing on RHEL 7 latest

Tags: rhel, mc

I am using RHEL 7.9 and installed `mc` with the following commands:

```
yum update
yum install mc
```

Options/Appearance menu item is missing.

Doing the same on RHEL 8.1 gives the Options/Appearance, probably it is a different version of `mc`.

- On rhel7 I have 1:4.8.7-11.el7
- On rhel8 I have 1:4.8.19-9.el8

**Question**

How can I install `mc` version to RHEL 7.9 which have Options/Appearance menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fetch the src rpm for MC 4.8.19 (I don't have a subscription, I've no idea where to get it). This should also work: `wget http://vault.centos.org/8-stream/AppStream/Source/SPackages/mc-4.8.19-9.el8.src.rpm`
2. `sudo dnf install rpm-build gcc make aspell-devel e2fsprogs-devel glib2-devel gpm-devel groff-base perl-generators pkgconfig slang-devel`
3. `rpmbuild --rebuild mc-4.8.19-9.el8.src.rpm`
4. `sudo rpm -Uvh /home/username/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/mc-4.8.19-9.el8.x86_64.rpm`